# Show that n^3 log n is Ω(n^3)

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I understand that in order to prove big Omega, we must pick values for c and n such that the property is satisfied, but which values would I know to pick? Is there a way to do this using the limit rule?

Comment: Generally you *don't* know right away what values will work, unless you've either 1) done many similar problems, or 2) carefully written down the definitions and what you want to show, as well as played around with the algebra. Do either of those apply to you?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of [big omega notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation) is that $f=\Omega(g)$ if
$$
\limsup_{x\to\infty}|f(x)/g(x)|>0.
$$
This means that there exists some $y\in \mathbb R$ and some $c>0$ such that for all $x>y$, we must have $|f(x)|>c|g(x)|$.

In this case, $f(x)=x^3\log x$ and $g(x)=x^3$. Choose $y=e$ and $c=1$. Then the statement $f=\Omega(g)$ follows because for all $x>e$, we have
$$
x^3\log x > x^3\log e= x^3.
$$